# Create a column called different by some conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table. Using select statement to get this output.

**Expected result**

```
    name        finish_position      official_rating     date                Difference     bsp
Camanche Grey        11                   NULL        2013-09-18                 0.00      72.53
Camanche Grey         4                   NULL        2013-11-08                 0.00      12.50
Camanche Grey         3                   NULL        2014-02-27                 0.00      24.00
Camanche Grey         6                    65         2014-04-24                 0.00      32.00
Camanche Grey        13                    63         2014-05-05                 0.00     109.06
Camanche Grey         1                    59         2014-07-04                 0.00       4.16
Camanche Grey         2                    65         2014-08-04       (59-65)= -6.00       5.10
Camanche Grey        12                    68         2014-10-28       (59-68)= -9.00      55.00
Camanche Grey         9                    62         2014-12-09       (59-62)= -3.00     110.89
Camanche Grey         5                    65         2015-01-08       (59-65)= -6.00      61.07
Camanche Grey         7                    60         2015-01-29       (59-60)= -1.00      12.54
Camanche Grey        11                    65         2015-04-08       (59-65)= -6.00      15.50
Camanche Grey         5                    63         2015-04-22       (59-63)= -4.00      36.07
Camanche Grey         1                    60         2015-07-14                 0.00       4.25
Camanche Grey         9                    62         2015-08-04       (62-62)=  0.00       5.30
Camanche Grey         8                    56         2016-01-22       (62-56)=  6.00      22.67
Camanche Grey         4                    52         2016-02-26       (62-52)= 10.00      11.76
Camanche Grey         7                    50         2016-03-31       (62-50)= 12.00       4.30
Camanche Grey         8                    48         2016-04-25       (62-48)= 14.00       6.31
Camanche Grey         4                    56         2016-07-12       (62-56)=  6.00       9.50
Camanche Grey         8                    47         2016-09-23       (62-47)= 15.00      23.47
Camanche Grey         9                    52         2017-06-20       (62-52)= 10.00     114.54
Camanche Grey         1                    50         2017-07-04                 0.00      15.51
Camanche Grey         3                    55         2017-07-20       (55-55)=  0.00       5.29
Camanche Grey         3                    48         2017-07-29       (55-48)=  7.00      15.51
```

Whenever finish_position is 1 then difference is 0. All above rows differences are 0 until this row (first row from top to bottom that finish_position is equal to 1) You can get the idea from the above table. I need to get the difference between each rows official_rating.

```
select test.*,
if(finish_position = 1 , @b:=@b+1,@b:=@b) block,
if(finish_position = 1 , @last_op:=official_rating,@last_op:=@last_op) last_opening_position,
cast(if(@b = 0 or finish_position = 1,0,@last_op - official_rating) as decimal(10,2)) different
from test
order by date;
```

The above code is to create and find the difference between the first set of rows(row 7 to row 13). I want to add some extra codes for supporting the below condition.
"Whenever the first set is done then we need to get opening official_rating value from the next row of the finish_position is equal to 1 row.

Example 1: difference should start from at official_rating is 62 (15th row), and not start from 60.

Example 2: difference should start from at official_rating is 55 (23rd row), and not start from 50.

You can get the idea from the above table and the fiddle output table.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86be4fed5d91e60f6f400df416376298)

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions for this.  If I understand correctly:

```
select t.*,
       (case when t.finish_position = 1 then 0
             else t0.finish_position - t.finish_position
        end) as difference
from (select t.*,
             max(case when finish_position = 1 then datec end) over (partition by sf_name order by datec) as prev_1
      from test t
     ) t left join
     test t0
     on t0.sf_name = t.sf_name and t0.datec = prev_1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=277211ea99704704c9fcda3a0cfe331f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: 23rd row difference should be 0. Please check my expected result table

Comment: @ZajjithVedha . . . Good catch.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: There is an error "Table 'fiddle_OEQOVIAIBDIESGTCNNVT.t' doesn't exist" in the fiddle

Comment: @ZajjithVedha . . . It should have the right fiddle now.

Comment: Please check the difference column from the expected result table that I mentioned above. I need to get difference values same like that. That fiddle output difference column has wrong values. Please check it